# Terraform cannot create azure VM in Germany West Central Region

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to create an `azure` vm in the `Germany West Central` region but I am getting the following error:

> Error: compute.VirtualMachinesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status= Code="SkuNotAvailable" Message="The requested size for resource '/subscriptions//resourceGroups/shared-rg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/jumphost' is currently not available in location 'germanywestcentral' zones '' for subscription ''. Please try another size or deploy to a different location or zones. See https://aka.ms/azureskunotavailable for details."
> │
> │   with module.jump_host_vm.azurerm_virtual_machine.vm,
> │   on modules/virtual-machine/main.tf line 1, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm":
> │    1: resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {

I am using the `Standard_A1_v2` size and SKU of `22.04-LTS`. Please fin my `terraform` code below:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name                  = var.vm_name 
  location              = var.location
  resource_group_name   = var.rg_name
  network_interface_ids = var.nic_id
  vm_size               = var.vm_size #"Standard_A1_v2"

  delete_os_disk_on_termination = true

  delete_data_disks_on_termination = true

  storage_image_reference  {
    publisher = var.storage_image_reference.publisher #"Canonical"
    offer     = var.storage_image_reference.offer     #"UbuntuServer"
    sku       = var.storage_image_reference.sku       #"20.04-LTS"
    version   = var.storage_image_reference.version   #"latest"
  }
  storage_os_disk  {
    name              = var.storage_os_disk.name              #"myosdisk1"
    caching           = var.storage_os_disk.caching           #"ReadWrite"
    create_option     = var.storage_os_disk.create_option     #"FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = var.storage_os_disk.managed_disk_type #"Standard_LRS"
  }

  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = true
  }
  tags = merge(var.common_tags)
}
```

and the values for the above is as follows:

```
jump_host_vm_name = "jumphost"
jump_host_vm_size = "Standard_A1_v2"
jump_host_storage_image_reference = {
  publisher = "Canonical"
  offer     = "UbuntuServer"
  sku       = "22.04-LTS"
  version   = "latest"
}
jump_host_storage_os_disk = {
  name              = "myosdisk"
  caching           = "ReadWrite"
  create_option     = "FromImage"
  managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
}
```

Can someone help me understand why it is not working? According to the azure site [1], this VM is available in the Germany region.

[1] - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/explore/global-infrastructure/products-by-region/?regions=all&products=virtual-machines

Comment: Open a ticket with Azure support

Comment: @Jananath Banuka - Refer to the suggested documentation in the error message https://aka.ms/azureskunotavailable which has information about what is cause and solution for this problem

Comment: In my view, the actual error behind the screen is that platform image "Canonical:UbuntuServer:22.04-LTS:latest" was not available. Try with 16.04-LTS. It will work.

Comment: Try these values: 
"Ubuntu-2204": {
        "publisher": "Canonical",
        "offer": "0001-com-ubuntu-server-jammy",
        "sku": "22_04-lts-gen2",
        "version": "latest"
      },

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the Canonical:UbuntuServer:22.04-LTS:latest" was not available and its under preview.  we can use bellowed version 16.04-LTS /19_10-daily-gen2
**For 16.04 version, VM size as "Standard_A1_v2"**
**For latest sku 19_10-daily-gen2, supported VM size will be Standard_DS2_v2**

```
 storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS" //"19_10-daily-gen2"
    version   = "latest"
  }
```

**Here is the command to get the supported versions of SKUs**

```
Get-AzVMImageSku -Location "Germany West Central" -PublisherName "Canonical" -Offer "UbuntuServer" | Select Skus
```

[image]

please find below sample code reference from [snippet](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine)
main tf as follows

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "***********"
}
data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "puvnet" {
    name                = "Public_VNET"
   resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = "Germany West Central"
  address_space       = ["10.19.0.0/16"]
  dns_servers         = ["10.19.0.4", "10.19.0.5"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "osubnet" {
  name                 = "Outer_Subnet"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.19.1.0/24"]
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.puvnet.name
}


resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
  name                = "testdemo"
  location                = "Germany West Central"
  resource_group_name     = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "testconfiguration1"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.osubnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "main" {
   name                  = "vmjumphost"
  location              = "Germany West Central"
  resource_group_name =  data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.main.id]
  vm_size               = "Standard_A1_v2"
   storage_image_reference {
    offer                 = "UbuntuServer"
    publisher             = "Canonical"
    sku                   = "19_10-daily-gen2"
    version   = "latest"
  }
  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "myosdisk1"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }
  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "hostname"
    admin_username = "********"
    admin_password = "*********"
  }
  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
  }
  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}
```

provider file as follow:

```
terraform {
  
      required_version = "~>1.3.3"
      required_providers {
        azurerm = {
           source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
           version = ">=3.0.0"
             }
           }
 }

 provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
    skip_provider_registration = true
}
```

Upon running on

```
terraform plan
```

[image]

upon apply

```
terraform apply -auto-approve
```

[image]

Verification from UI

[image]

[image]